# Retrive relation on a polymorphic model

Tags: php, laravel, iteration, eloquent

I have a `Game` model that is "static". Containing game information and such, and users can comment on all games.

`Games` model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
}
```

And then I have a `Comment` model. This has a `User` relation and a `Comments` relation.

```
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

What I want to do is to fetch the 10 games sorted by the latest comment top, be able to display who made the comment, and when.

I have this query that seems to do the job, but it makes an absurd amount of queries. Can I somehow keep the queries to a minimum?

```
    $games = Game::join('comments', 'games.id', '=', 'comments.commentable_id')
    ->where('comments.commentable_type', Game::class)
    ->latest('comments.created_at')
    ->groupBy('games.id')
    ->take(10)
    ->withCount('comments')
    ->get()->each(function($games){
        $games->comment = $games->comments()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        $games->user = User::find($games->comment->user_id);
        return $games;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which version of Laravel is used, so I am going to presume it is 5.x. If that is incorrect, please notify me and update your post with such relevant information

I am not sure exactly how to reduce the queries for comments but the suggestion below should allow remove the loop of queries for the user on each game.

#### Eager Loading

(Nested) [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) - utilizing the [`with()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_with) method - can be used to populate the `user` property for each item in the collection:

```
$games = Game::join('comments', 'games.id', '=', 'comments.commentable_id')
->where('comments.commentable_type', Game::class)
->latest('comments.created_at')
->groupBy('games.id')
->take(10)
->with('comment.user')
->withCount('comments')
```

#### Variable naming

The lambda/closure passed to [`each()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_each) accepts a parameter named `$games`. Isn't it actually a representation of a *game*? If so, `$game` would be more appropriate. Additionally, other developers reading the code may be confused because `$games` is also used for the assignment of the collection.